# How to use QResource to read a file?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I've a text file which is added to a resource file in qt's `pro` file. I'd like to access this file via `boost::filesystem`. I've learned that I have to use `QResource` in order to do so, I've tried few things:

```
QResource resource("./Resources/setting_files/accepted_file_extensions.txt");
boost::filesystem3::ifstream fin(resource.absoluteFilePath().toStdString());
```

and it doesn't work, but why?

Comment: I don't understand why you posted this question. The answer to your previous question about this tells you to use QFile, which you should. QResource (as the docs I linked to there) is to load external resource files. Resources compiled in to your app are not visible on the filesystem, so neither boost nor plain `open` calls can see them.

Comment: @Mat, in the answer to my previous question the alternative is given, either use QResource OR QFile.

Comment: Yes, but you're supposed to read the linked documentation. QResource is for loading external resource files.

Answer (score 1):

QResource is used for loading external binary resources which basically are files that are a compound of other several different files (images, documents, etc.).

The workflow is:

- you create a resource file (.qrc extension) that specifies the files to be combined as a binary, using the specific Qt QRC markup tags;
- you combine all the files in the resource data binary file using the command (for linux) `rcc -binary myresource.qrc -o myresource.rcc`;
- finally you include the resource (dynamically) using a QResource instance by registering it through `QResource::registerResource("/path/to/myresource.rcc");` .

This is very helpfull for importing several files using only one file. This is also very helpfull for embeded sytems.

Source: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html#external-binary-resources